# OpenGL ES, How should I load a new texture from an open file in onDrawFrame (Android)

Tags: android, file-io, opengl-es

I am writing an Android application to play video from a binary file using OpenGL ES 2.0. There is one big video file with totally unformatted binary pixel data in it (1000's of frames worth). I am using RandomAccessFile to open the file, navigate to  the correct point and pull out the pixel data for the desired frame.

I have initially done this **very** crudely by opening the file and closing it again in each call of onDrawFrame.

```
    //The following sits within the onDrawFrame activity:

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L
    long frame = 0;
    frame = time/10;

    int w = 640; //width in pixels
    int h = 512; //height in pixels
    int nP = w * h; //number of pixels in frame and size of frame in bytes

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[nP]; //array to hold one frame


    try {

    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("//sdcard/8bitvid.bin", "r"); //open the video file

    f.seek(nP*frame);   //navigate to the correct frame
    f.read(byteArray);  //read frame
    f.close();          //close file
    }
```

I realise this is wrong in so many ways but I have just migrated to Java from Labview, it's quite a jump! So my questions are:

-How should I keep the file open between calls of onDrawFrame?

-How do I pass a variable (i.e. frame number) between interations of onDrawFrame?

A quick explanation or just a pointer to a relevant example would be great.

Thanks

Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple of things... You probably have color information in your binary so you should include that in your array initialization -

```
  int nP = w * h *3;  // RGB = 3 bytes, RGBA = 4 bytes.
```

The other thing is that everytime ondrawframe is called you reopen the file.. you only need to do that once.  You could declare a RandomAccessFile f as a private member of the renderer class, and on the constuctor open the file.  If you leave it open you won't reopen it every time.  This may or may not be an issue actually.  To keep track of how many frames you've seen though, I'd suggest to make a private int in the class and increment it every time you draw the frame.

So here is what I suggest:

```
class glVideoRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
  private int frameNumber = 0;
  RandomAccessFile f;


  public glVideoRenderer(){
     try{
        f= new RandomAccessFile("//sdcard/8bitvid.bin", "r");
      }
      catch(...
  }


  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused){
     ..... // whatever you need here    
     f.seek(nP*frameNumber++);   //navigate to the correct frame,  frameNumber increments after the line is executed
     ....... // update whatever you need here.
  }

}
```

Comment: Paulczak, This worked a treat! Along with array initialisation out of the loop it gave me a 10x speed improvement. (I think I am now limited by the sdcard access speed. I wonder if running a parallel threads for reading and rendering would improve this.)

Comment: This depends... If you have a mutlicore system running this then probably yes, on a single core it may reduce the perception of lag between frames.  Is it running slowly right now - what kind of frame rate are you able to achieve?

Comment: Paulczak, I'm getting 25fps on a 1GHz Tablet, but I have faster hardware order. I'd like to get to 60fps, i.e. 20MB/s off the card. There are sdcards that can handle it, but I don't know if the tablet sdcard interface can. At the moment the card is idle whilst the data is being converted to int and then sent to the GPU, when in theory it could be reading the next frame in parallel. (I tried speed up the rendering by using an 8 bit single channel luminance texture but driver support for 8bit textures seems patchy, it works on the emulator but comes out black on two devices I've tried.)

Comment: How much can you buffer into main memory?  Can you fit the whole video into main memory?  Having a thread read into a 3 or 4 entry circular buffer is one good option.  The other thing too is that at some point you'll need to be able to read as fast or faster than you are displaying... Have you considered compressing the source?  If you are on a tablet and displaying at native resolution and not turning on dithering, you're likely only displaying at 6bit color, so you could make some good savings like that...  (just read off 6bits by right shifting and bitwise anding with 0x3f).